# Why parse int throws exception for decimal numbers?

Tags: java, android

If I enter any number in EditText I dont get exception. But if I enter a number with decimal I get

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "55555.96"

The value in String inputamount is OK for decimal number whereas when it is parsed for int it gives this error only when it is decimal number.
When I tried with parseInt,valueOf,long .. in all I get this exception.

EditText xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:padding="-11dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789.00"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
    android:hint="Payment"
    android:maxWidth="222dp" />
```

code:

```
 amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 String inputamount = amount.getText().toString();
 int iii = Integer.valueOf( inputamount.toString());
 int ii=0;
 ii=Integer.parseInt(inputamount.toString());
 long lg=Integer.parseInt(inputamount);
```

Comment: Because 55555.96 is not an integer? You can parse it as a `double` and round later.

Comment: Directly do `long lg=Long.parseLong(inputamount.toString());`

Comment: `55555.96` is not Integer. You can use `Long.parseLong()` for long type variable, and `Float.parseFloat()` for float type instead of `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: I used like this as told by Thilo, it worked.
 Double dblInputAmount1 = Double.parseDouble(inputamount.toString());

Answer (score 0):

***Use these lines of code***

```
 amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 String inputamount = amount.getText().toString();
 if(inputamount.contains("."))
 {
   float jjj =Float.valueOf(inputamount.toString())
 }
 else
 {
   int iii = Integer.valueOf( inputamount.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String inputamount = amount.getText().toString();
int ii=0;

double d =Double.parseDouble(inputamount.toString().trim());
ii = (int) d;
```